# Terminal execution shows .rb steps before .feature scenario steps

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, cucumber, output, bdd

### Description of Problem

I am having a "problem" while creating Cucumber automation with Ruby. My terminal is showing the .rb steps before the .feature scenario steps, which is really annoying for readability.

```
Information
Ruby: 3.0.3p157
Terminal: Git 2.34.1
Cucumber: 7.1.0
```

My feature file contains:

```
@home_screen
Feature: Tests for home screen functionality

  @default
  Scenario: Default values on home screen is Foot and Centimeter
    Given I land on the home screen
    Then left unit picker value should be 'Foot'
    And right unit picker value should be 'Centimeter'

  Scenario: Show All button should be enabled at launch
    Given I land on home screen
    Then the Show All button is enabled
    When I press on Clear button
    Then the Show All button is disabled

  @conversions
  Scenario Outline: Verify default conversions
    Given I land on home screen
    When I type <target> to target field
    Then I should should see <result> as the result

      Examples:
      | target | result |
      | 1      | 12     |
      | 2      | 24     |
      | 3      | 36     |
      | 9      | 106    |
```

My step definitions contain:

```
Given('I land on home screen') do
  puts 'I am at the home screen'
end

Then('left unit picker value should be {string}') do |string|
  puts "left unit picker value is #{string}"
end

And('right unit picker value should be {string}') do |string|
  puts "right unit picker value is #{string}"
end

When('I press on Clear button') do
  puts 'Clear button is pressed'
end

When('I type {int} to target field') do |target|
  puts "Target is: #{target}."
end

Then(/the Show All button is (enabled|disabled)/) do |state|
  state == 'enabled' ? puts('Button is enabled') : puts('Button is disabled')
end

Then('I should should see {int} as the result') do |result|
  puts "Result is: #{result}."
end
```

### Terminal Execution of One Scenario

[image: terminal execution of one scenario]

### Expected Output

[image: Expected Output]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Well, your step definitions are `puts` so you you literally tell to print those messages, It is not showing the steps, it is printing the message you told it to print. What else would you expect here?

Comment: Hello, I was expecting the Given/When/Then to show up before the puts, as intended. I am new to ruby and cucumber, so I'm not sure what you mean, but I want to output this way:

Given I land on the home screen 
     /  I am at the home screen

I cant format the comment, but the given should come before the puts

Comment: `puts` is a command to print out the message on the screen, which is what's happening. Your steps are not doing anything - there's no interaction with the page in it at all. I assume these `puts` are there as temporary placeholder, you normally do not print to the output from your tests

Comment: Yes, it's just a placeholder used for learning, but the cucumber steps should still show up first, as it's more logical, besides, the course I'm taking displays the correct order for the output, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZQKp.png
I followed the course's code word for word just in case and their output order is different

Comment: I wouldn't say it is more logical - it is a difference whether the step is displayed when it starts vs when it finishes. I'd argue that the latter is more logical as you cannot know if the step succeeded before its finished (so you don;t know how to actually print it yet). The problem with tutorials is that they are not updated, and software and libraries are. For now, just ignore this and focus on more important things, like actually implementing these steps or reasons for/against cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

### Treat Steps as Assertions, Not Message Generators

In Cucumber, the body of a step is executed *before* determining whether or not the Gherkin statement it exercises has succeeded. The problem you're having is that you're treating the step as a result to be reported directly rather than as a test assertion that makes the Gherkin statement pass or fail. Since the body of each step in your example creates output to STDOUT via [Kernel#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts), the step's output may print to the screen before the status of the related Gherkin statement is known. In any case, it *will* print the messages in your steps to standard output because the step definitions specifically tell it to do so.

Instead of printing results directly from your steps, treat steps more like assertions that return a Boolean. The [cucumber-ruby documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby#automate-your-specification) provides some useful examples of this. If you think of the Gherkin statements more like RSpec descriptions, and Cucumber steps more like RSpec expectations rather than status messages, you will get more sensible results on standard output.

### Some General BDD Advice

Cucumber steps really ought not to be sending output directly to STDOUT in the first place because it creates confusion (as you discovered). Instead:

- If you want to log something, use the [Logger module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html).
- If you want to print errors or other information from steps, use `$stderr.puts` and direct it somewhere other than your terminal via shell redirection or a Ruby file handle.
- If you're using Cucumber for low-level testing, consider moving those tests (especially any noisy tests) to RSpec or MiniTest unit tests instead so as not to pollute your Cucumber tests or output.

Cucumber can be abused in all sorts of ways, but it's not a substitute for unit or functional testing. It's really best suited for integration testing and domain-level executable documentation than unit testing, but your mileage there may vary.

Comment: It just seemed more logical to me to go in the order of "When I do something => something happens", and both of the courses I'm taking on the subject, the output it is as such, so it's probably some local configuration/framework version, as both courses are outdated. I agree on the logger point, and we use one at work. But as my courses are at beginner's level, they take this approach. This thing is more a hindrance than an actual problem, so I'll just have to live with it, no problem. I appreciate the comprehensive response, Mr. Jacobs. Thank you!